# How do I get path coefficients in mediation model from ADE and ACME (mediation package)?

Tags: r, mediation, path-model

I am conducting a mediation analysis with the mediation package in R. As a result I get values for an average direct effect (ADE) and an average causal mediation effect (ACME).

In the literature such mediations are often drawn as path models in which X represents the predictor, M the mediator and Y the dependent variable. X -> Y is then called **c'**, X -> M becomes **a** and M -> Y is called **b**.

As I see it, the ADE represents the path **c'**. ACME is the product of paths **a** and **b**, that is **ab**.

How do I get values for **a** and **b**?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `mediate()`, you need to supply two models: the mediator model (`M ~ T + X1 + X2`) and the outcome model (`Y ~ M + T + X1 + X2`). The coefficient for `T` in the mediator model is **a**, and the coefficient for `M` in the outcome model is **b**. Note that these values only (directly) relate to the ACME and ADE if the outcome and mediator are continuous and there is no treatment-mediator interaction on the outcome.